# Wouldn't this always become 0?

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to understand how to calculate $α$ in the following, but my brain tells me that it always will become $0$:

[image]

If $α_0$ is a known value, and as the text says $α$ is a parameter, no function and differentiate it to respect to $s$,  it will always become zero.  Why is this not the case?